# Issues getting hover background color to take place of whole block

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar and I am having issues getting the hover's background color to take place of the entire area I want it to be in. I want it to be the entire block of the list item as well as the padding I have created. Right now it is only changing the color of the link's title name.

I created a fiddle to show what is happening.

https://jsfiddle.net/aqdw7mh3/

I have tried adding `width: 100%;` to:

```
.spectator_nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

and

```
.spectator_nav li a:hover {
background-color: #282828;
-o-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
-ms-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
-moz-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
-webkit-transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
/* ...and now for the proper property */
transition:color .4s ease-out, background .3s ease-in;
}
```

This did nothing to help my case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `a` to the size of the block. This way, it will fill up the block and the background will too.

---

Removed/changed some things but hopefully this is what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/aqdw7mh3/4/

Comment: Your other answer worked, but for some reason the hover isn't touching the bottom of the nav bar.

Comment: @Paul what do you mean; do you want the text to be at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Disregard that last comment, I figured it out. One side comment though. If you look at my fiddle(I updated it), you see how the hover goes all the way to the left. If I try to add `margin-left: 10px;` to my `.spectator_nav li` and it is making each list item have a margin left of that. What can I add it to so that that is only pushes the entire list items over, but doesn't affect each list item?

Comment: @Paul: I used a horizontal-only padding to push blocks. See edit.

Comment: Well I want the top border radius, so I want to bush the list items with a margin left past that, so that when it is covered upon the border radius still stays the normal color.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for all of your help.